# Function difference in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am writing a function difference to find the error or the difference between the exact and the approximate solution by using the Euler function, this error is going to be a vector, but I receive this error message. Can you help me to figure out this problem? I am going to attach a screenshot of my code. Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7MCp.png)

at line     8 of function functiondifference ( C:\Users\82109\Desktop\Scilab\Exercise_11\Q_1\functiondifference.sci line 16 )
at line    40 of executed file C:\Users\82109\Desktop\Scilab\Exercise_11\Q_1\functiondifference.sci

feval: Wrong type for input argument #1: A real matrix expected.

Answer (score 0):

`feval()` takes the handle of the function to evaluate as **last** argument, not as the first one:
https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/feval.html